# Android Talkback: Stop talkback from reading aloud buttons of alert dialog

Tags: android, talkback

I am creating alert dialogs like that:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.activity);

builder.setTitle(title);
builder.setMessage(message);
builder.setCancelable(false);
builder.setNegativeButton(this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_close), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});

return builder.create();
```

Now talkback is reading aloud:

```
alert [title]
[message]
close
```

I dont want talkback to say "alert" and "close". How can i prevent talkback from reading that aloud? It's just too much noise when an alert dialog pops up.

Comment: What you want? If you want to remove title and message just remove builder.setTitle(title);
builder.setMessage(message);

Comment: I wrote what i want. I wrote: "I dont want talkback to say "alert" and "close"". I never said anything about removing the title or the message. That would make no sense at all.

Comment: Means you just want to show message to user.

Comment: No! I want to show everything to the user! I want talkback to only read aloud the message! That is what i wrote in my post.